# How to write Jest test cases for React container components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I am new in React-Redux and I want to write unit test cases in Jest for my React components. However,I don't know how to write test cases for React container component.`en

```js
import CombinedPanels from '../containers/CombinedPanels';

export class DapDropdowns extends Component {
 
  componentDidMount() {
    const { selectedDivision } = this.props;
    this.props.fetchDap(selectedDivision);
    this.props.fetchReportType();
    
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.selectedDivision !== this.props.selectedDivision) {
      const { selectedDivision } = nextProps;
      this.props.fetchDap(selectedDivision);
    }
  }

  onDivisionChange = (nextDivision) => {
    this.props.selectDivision(nextDivision);
  }

  onBranchChange = (nextBranch) => {
    this.props.selectBranch(nextBranch);
    const { selectedDivision, fiscalYear } = this.props;
    this.props.fetchFiscalYear(selectedDivision, nextBranch, fiscalYear);
  }

  render() {


    const { selectedDivision, reportType, fiscalYear, divisionBranchDropdown } = this.props;
    let branchesData = divisionBranchDropdown.filter(dap => dap.sbuid == selectedDivision);

  
    return (
        <div>
        <CombinedPanels />
        </div>
    );
  }
}



export default DapDropdowns;
```

ter code here`

Comment: Don't use componentWillReceiveProps it is treated as unsafe.

Comment: Test them line by line with Enzyme. As any other component. The question is too broad for SO. What did you try and what were the problems?